# Read lines into JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am using node.js and want to read lines which contain an "=" into a json object and output it as a json object.

This code reads the lines and works correctly:

```
var     lazy    = require("lazy"),
fs  = require("fs");
new lazy(fs.createReadStream('sysctl.conf')).lines.forEach(function(line){

     if(line.toString().indexOf("=") > -1) {
    sysArray.push(line);
    console.log("Contains =" + line);
    }
    else {

    //  console.log("Not contain = " + line)
    }


 });
```

I'm currently pushing the items to an array, however I think due to a time delay the array appears to have no objects in when I run this code:

```
 var arrayLength = sysArray.length;
 console.log("Array Length:" + arrayLength)

 for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
   console.log(sysArray[i]);
}
```

Essentially I would like to create a JSON object similar to this:

Where this is a sample line:
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=1

```
{

  “sysctl”: {
        “net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter”: “1”,
        “morevalues”: “morevalues”
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) :

```
var myObj = {};
new lazy(fs.createReadStream('sysctl.conf')).lines.forEach(function(line) {
    var tmp = line.split('=');
    // if line = "my.conf=1" then tmp = ["my.conf", "1"];
    myObj[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj));
```